# Getting hostname of the computer connected to the ssh session

Tags: ssh

As part of our deployment script for one of our apps I'm trying to log the date, time, and other relevant information for the deployment.

The way we have it set up, developers use a generic "app" account to perform deployments, so logging the user wouldn't be particularly helpful.

Would it be possible to get the hostname of the machine that connected to the SSH session?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an environment variable you can look for called `SSH_CONNECTION` that gets set when you log in with `ssh`. If you want the hostname, you may need to do a reverse lookup with `dig -x <ip address>`.

From the man page:

```
 SSH_CONNECTION
          Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: client ip-address, client port
          number, server ip-address and server port number.
```

Comment: This would work very badly for secure accountability, because users could simply type `SSH_CONNECTION=sneaky_sneaky /path/to/yourscript evil-params` and you would not know the originator.

Comment: True but a secure method was not what was asked for. I also assume that the logging of the ssh connection would be done before the user receives a prompt (i.e. in a .bashrc or some other startup script). If you wanted a proper secure method of accountability you'd not have them all logging in with the same user account.

Comment: For sure.  Shared accounts are to be avoided.  I know he didn't ask for it to be secure, but I thought it was worth mentioning, because there are not a lot of reasons you would need accountability but not need that accountability to be nontrivial to circumvent.

Comment: Good call. Upvoted your comment.

Comment: I have marked this one as the correct answer as it does get the hostname that connected. I wanted it to go a bit further (the hostname from the user's machine), as we all connect through a VPN (same ip for everyone). You guys are right about the need to change the setup so that each user can use their own account. I was trying to avoid having multiple copies of the repository on the server (and the potential of having different developer with the repo on a different revision). I'll look into it.

Comment: You can store the host name like this: 
`SSH_CLIENT_HOSTNAME=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs dig +short -x)`

Answer (score 2):

While the environment variable SSH_CONNECTION may be the best method. Other methods exist.

- ssh and other logins are typically logged in /var/log/secure on many linux distributions.
- Give developers individual logins, and have them use sudo to do app deploys, or have their users have group write access to the app.